# AutoLayout warning after update tableview cell frame with UIWebView inside

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom TableViewCell with image, label, and webview inside, after calculate webview size I update cell height only for cells which loaded web content.

```
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffa58c20680 UIImageView:0x7ffa58c1fe50.top == UILabel:0x7ffa588c9660'Nguy\U00ean Tuyen'.top>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffa58c20720 UILabel:0x7ffa588c9660'Nguy\U00ean Tuyen'.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffa588c94e0.topMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffa58c20950 V:[UIImageView:0x7ffa58c1fe50]-(16)-[UIWebView:0x7ffa588c9ee0]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffa58c20a90 V:[UIWebView:0x7ffa588c9ee0]-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7ffa588c99d0'1 Tr\U1ea3 l\U1eddi']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffa58c20ae0 UILabel:0x7ffa588c99d0'1 Tr\U1ea3 l\U1eddi'.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffa588c94e0.bottomMargin + 5>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ffa58c295b0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7ffa588c94e0(0.5)]>"
```

)

Please tell me how to fix this!
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please say what warning you are getting?

Comment: >Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
 Try this: 
  (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
  (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
   Quote above
)
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.

Comment: A screenshot of your constraints would help diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases when it comes to AutoLayout warnings:

**1. Ambiguity**

In this case, there are not enough constraints and so the Interface Builder can't resolve the position or the size of the subview.

**2. Conflict**

In this case, there are too many constraints. You can either resolve them manually or decrease the priority of the less necessary ones from 1000.
Constraints with a priority less than 1000 are considered optional.

Comment: Thank you I fixed by change priority to 999